# is it possible to update html content in a page using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page with *textbox* and *button*.

> textbox
>   button

If I enter some text in *textbox* and on click on the *button*, it should update the HTML page like this:

> text entered with h1 tag
>   textbox
>   button

Is this possible with Javascript?

Comment: Yes sure, this is possible. Is that the reason you asked this question ?

Comment: can u tell me the function used in javascript to make this possible

Comment: How about reading up on JavaScript and the DOM?

Comment: Yes, i think you should first have a look at [Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)

Comment: Using DOM i can show that text at that point of time. once i refresh the page get resets. but here i want to save the text in HTML page with some h tag

Comment: Then you should save the values somewhere, what about a database.

Comment: without database is it possible? and i want use only JS not any other scripting language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Tempted to leave it at that, but...

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var h1 = document.createElement("H1");
  var txt = document.getElementById('mytext');
  document.body.insertBefore(h1, txt);
  document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    h1.innerHTML = txt.value;
  });
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mytext" value="" />
<input type="button" id="mybutton" value="Send it" />
```

Comment: Thanks for snippet, But if i again click on button the text should save with another h tag

Comment: Actually this is not i required...i think its not possible...Any way thanks Mackan for your great help..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('textarea').keyup(function () {
  var mystring = $(this).val();  
  $('p').text(mystring);
});
```

Sure, with javascript.